# Program printing incorrect symbolic constants values

Tags: c, printf, unsigned-integer, conversion-specifier

I am currently learning C and I am attempting to complete the K&R exercise 2-1. (Write a program to determine the ranges of char, short, int, and long variables, both
signed and unsigned, by printing appropriate values from standard headers and by direct computation.) I have written the following code to achieve this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    printf("Unsigned Variable Ranges\n");
    printf("Unsigned char:  %d    %d\n", 0, UCHAR_MAX);
    printf("Unsigned short: %d    %d\n", 0, USHRT_MAX);
    printf("Unsigned int:   %d    %d\n", 0, UINT_MAX);
    printf("Unsigned long:  %d    %d\n", 0, ULONG_MAX);
}
```

My thought process through this is to use the symbolic constants found in limits.h and float.h to print the minimum and maximum values in my program. The char and short values are printing correctly, but the int and long values are printing as -1. The terminal reads:

```
Unsigned Variable Ranges
Unsigned char:  0    255
Unsigned short: 0    65535
Unsigned int:   0    -1
Unsigned long:  0    -1
```

Is this an error on my part or is this a compiler/Visual Studio error?

Comment: use %u for unsigned

Comment: Well, `UINT_MAX` (not speaking of `ULONG_MAX`) is inherently larger than `INT_MAX`, which is the maximum value that can be printed using `%d`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unsigned integers you have to use the conversion specifier `u` instead of `d`. Also for the type long integer you have to use the length modifier `l`.

So the calls of printf can look like

```
printf("Unsigned char:  %u    %u\n", 0, UCHAR_MAX);
printf("Unsigned short: %u    %u\n", 0, USHRT_MAX);
printf("Unsigned int:   %u    %u\n", 0, UINT_MAX);
printf("Unsigned long:  %d    %lu\n", 0, ULONG_MAX);
```

For the types `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` you could also use the conversion specifier `%d` provided that the type `int` can contain all values of the unsigned types after the integer promotions of the types.

Comment: @SupportUkraine And what is wrong?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Thanks. It was a typo. :) I did not take into account that there are two specifiers.:)

Comment: @SupportUkraine I am under expression that he uses ULONG_MIN.:)

Answer (score 1):

When using printf you give the format string specifies what type you are printing. `%d` means integer and as both maximum value for unsigned int and the max value for unsigned long can not fit in integer it overflows and is printed as `-1`.

Comment: I wouldn't quite call it an overflow, but rather that `UINT_MAX` is `11111...` in binary, and interpreting it with the first bit as a sign bit would make it negative `11111...`. By two's complement, this is equivalent to `-1` (the resultant output).

Comment: hm well it kind of is, we try to print an unsigned int value that is a valid unsigned int value and it does not fit in an int value, thus it overflows. Maybe a matter of terminology

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, let's suppose that `unsigned int` is four bytes wide.  `UINT_MAX` is going to be `0xffffffff`.  However, you're printing that value as an `int` (because of the `%d`).  As a signed integer, `0xffffffff` means `-1` because of [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

What you want to do is print `UINT_MAX` as an `unsigned int` which you can do with `%u` instead of `%d`.  Similarly, for `ULONG_MAX`, you need to use `%lu`.